# convergence in $L^{2}$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, lebesgue-measure, uniform-convergence, pointwise-convergence

> Problem:Let $f_n: [0, 1] → R (n = 1, 2,...)$ Be the functions defined by

> $f_{n}(x)=\begin{cases}0&\text{ for }x=0
>  \\ n^{4/7}\sin {1/x^2}&\text{ for }x\in \left (  0,1/n \right ]
> \\ 0&\text{ for }x\in \left ( 1/n,1 \right )
> \\ 1&\text{ for } x=1\end{cases}$

> In what sense (in the Lebesgue spatial norm $L^{2}[0, 1]$, on average, punctually, almost everywhere, to a degree) does the sequence {fn} converge?
> Justify your answers. Find the limit function.

The "average" convergence comes from the pointwise-convergence,  but uniform and $L^2$... I don't know how to test them, please help me

Thanks for any Hints

Comment: You need to define these terms.

Answer (score 0):

What do you need to show for uniform convergence? Maybe you can find a sequence $(x_n)$ such that $f_n(x_n)$ does not converge to 0. You may want to make the $\sin(\frac{1}{x^2})$ constant on this sequence.

Comment: "Your function is bounded, independently of $n$ by 1." Really?

Comment: damn, it was late yesterday. I took that out.